# Django: How to customize a form ChoiceField display?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating a minimalist shop with Django.

```
class CardOrderForm(forms.Form):
    order = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="",
        choices=ORDER_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect)

ORDER_CHOICES = (
    ('CARDS_100_G', 'Pack de 100 cartes génériques'),
    ('CARDS_200_G', 'Pack de 200 cartes génériques'),
    ('CARDS_500_G', 'Pack de 500 cartes génériques'))
```

Then, I created an object to map prices to order choices:

```
ORDER_PRICES = {
    # Without/With TAXES
    'CARDS_100_G': (39, 46.80),
    'CARDS_200_G': (69, 82.80),
    'CARDS_500_G': (149, 178.80))}
```

Currently, in my template, I have `{{ form.order }}` which displays a raw list of 3 choices like this:

- Pack de 100 cartes génériques
- Pack de 200 cartes génériques
- Pack de 500 cartes génériques

However, I can't find a way to customize this display to be able to add the price next to the item. I'd like to have this result:

- Pack de 100 cartes génériques - 39€
- Pack de 200 cartes génériques - 69€
- Pack de 500 cartes génériques - 149€

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by *adding some text after each choice*?

Comment: I reformulated my question from the beginning, hope it will be clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new set of choices dynamically.

```
ORDER_CHOICES_WITH_PRICES = [
    (key, "%s - %s€" % (val, ORDER_PRICES[key][0]))
    for key, val in ORDER_CHOICES
]
```

Comment: Thanks It works, but it's definitely a workaround since I can't handle any HTML this way. This should be done in the template instead of Python. I'm very surprised there's no way to do this in Django.

Comment: Very surprised there's no way to do *what*? You didn't mention anything about HTML. Why should it be done in the template?

Comment: Plus, it prevents me from formating the price as I want (for example I get `23.4€` instead of `23,40€`

Comment: I'm triying to modify how information is formatted/displayed, this is obviousloy the template purpose. I just think there should be a way to display a list of choices in a custom way, directly in the template. Perhaps Django-crispy would allow this.